# Unable to read a file when filepath is passed as an argument

Tags: python, file-handling, configparser, errno

I am running the python script from a Network Drive using a .bat file
I am using a config file to read the input files. The config file has the path of the input file.
path.

In Config file:

```
[APP]
path = "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Documents\PythonRun\Scripts\AATEST\do\products.txt"
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
import configparser

configParser = configparser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = r'\\NetworkPath\Subfolder\Users\Me\New folder\config.txt'
configParser.read(configFilePath)
path = configParser.get('APP', 'path')
```

using the 'path' as :

```
product = readFile(path)

def readFile(fileName):
        print(fileName)
        fileObj = open(fileName, "r") #fails here OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
        words = fileObj.read().splitlines() #puts the file into an array
        fileObj.close()
        return words
```

This fails with the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\Documents\\PythonRun\\Scripts\\AATEST\\do\\products.txt"'
```

I have also tried changing the file path set up call as :

```
path = r'{}'.format(configParser.get('APP', 'path')) #
```

However, this fails with the same error.

Not sure what is being missed here!

Comment: Maybe try '/' or '\\' instead of '\' since '\' is an escape character. Not sure if that is the problem, but it's worth a try

Comment: nope. doesn't work!

Comment: before you assign the product var print the type of “path”, that should help you to figure out how to fix it, i think

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
[APP]
path = "C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Documents\PythonRun\Scripts\AATEST\do\products.txt"
```

It should be:

```
[APP]
path = C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Documents\PythonRun\Scripts\AATEST\do\products.txt
```

'path' to be set without the quotes in the config file.
Thanks.